# How to attach data with $route and access it on $routeChangeStart

Tags: angularjs, routes

What I want to do is attach some data while configuring the route like the following:

```
$routeProvider
  .when('/home', {
    templateUrl: 'main.html',
    controller: 'HomeController',
    myData: 'my-data-home' // my custom data
  })
  .when('/profile', {
    templateUrl: 'profile.html',
    myData: 'my-data-profile' // my custom data
  })
  .when('/404', {
    templateUrl: '404.html'
  })
  .when('/login', {
    templateUrl: 'login.html',
    controller: 'LoginController',
    myData: 'my-data-login' // my custom data
  })
  .otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/404'
  });
```

And I want to access it back from my `$routeChangeStart` event listener:

```
$rootScope.$on( "$routeChangeStart", function(event, next, current) {
  // here I want to access myData for the next route
});
```

Is it possible to do this in AngularJS? If yes, how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Your approach will work. The properties will be available on:

```
next.$$route
```

I use this approach to add properties to use creating dynamic navbars.

Answer (score 0):

The following code can be used to get the attached data with route

```
$rootScope.$on( "$routeChangeStart", function(event, next, current) {
  var myData = next.myData; // here I want to access myData for the next route
});
```